# laravel-5.8:show date with changed format in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi i wants to show date in this 2015-10-28 format from db but it says:
  "Unknown or bad timezone (Wed Jul 10 2019 16:30:00 GMT+0500"

controller:

```
   $form=Day::find(1);/*->day()->get();*/
   //   $dd=new Date().toISOString();
    $date=\Carbon\Carbon::parse('m/d/Y h:i:s',$form->selecteddatetime);
    return view('calendar.index');
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

We can use Carbon -> See more: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting

*1. toDateString() or toDateTimeString() (if you want to get Y-m-d H:i:s)*

Ex: **you want get date time now: Y-m-d H:i:s (2015-10-28 10:00:00)**

```
Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()
```

*2. format*

Ex:  **you wants to show date in this 2015-10-28 format**

```
$date = Carbon::parse($form->selecteddatetime)->format('Y-m-d');
```

*3. Use Carbon createFromFormat:*

**See more** https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization

```
Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $time, $tz);
```

Ex:

```
echo Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H', '1975-05-21 22')->toDateTimeString(); // 1975-05-21 22:00:00
```

> If you dont want use Carbon >> use date php

```
$dateTime = strtotime($form->selecteddatetime);
$date = date("Y-m-d", $dateTime);
```

Hope it will help you. Thanks

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '$date' (T_VARIABLE) at  $date = Carbon::parse($form->selecteddatetime)->format('Y-m-d');

Comment: what is time format in your db $form->selecteddatetime? @programmer0001

Comment: $dateTime = strtotime($form->selecteddatetime);
$date = date("Y-m-d", $dateTime); @programmer0001 you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('m/d/Y h:i:s',$form->selecteddatetime);

$date->toDateString();
```

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Carbon' not found

Comment: Add use Carbon\Carbon;
or change it to
date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('m/d/Y h:i:s',$form->selecteddatetime);

Answer (score 0):

If you want format like `yyyy-mm-dd`:

```
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($form->selecteddatetime)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (Wed Jul 10 2019 16:30:00 GMT+0500

Comment: what is time format in your db `$form->selecteddatetime`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`{{  date('F nS, Y - g:iA' ,strtotime($form->created_at)) }}`